# How to customize HTML response in service stack exception?

Tags: servicestack

I have a legacy application that uses hidden iframes to upload content to a webserver.  During application startup, the document.domain is set to a particular value in the browser.  Any html response from the server that is to be included in the iframe also need to set the document.domain to the same value, otherwise same origin policy will be violated.  In the case of an exception, service stack will take a DTO and generate some HTML around it. However, this html does not include some script to set the document.domain to the desired value.  My question then is, is it possible to customize the HTML of the response sent back in an error?

Looking at the docs:

https://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#custom-exceptions

it says we can "throw or return an HttpError letting you customize the Http Headers and Status Code and HTTP Response body to get exactly what you want on the wire".  I saw the example under the subheading of "HttpError with a Custom Response DTO" (https://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#httperror-with-a-custom-response-dto) using a custom DTO, which will get fed into service stack, and will appear within the body of the HTML.  But, can I get more control so I can customize the HTML to include some custom javascript (document.domain setting) within a script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return your own custom HTML Error Page have a look at [Fallback Error Pages](https://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#fallback-error-pages) where you can assign which custom Error page to return when using either [#Script Pages](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-pages) or [ServiceStack.Razor](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-razor).

Comment: That looks pretty close to what I'd want.  I'm on ancient version of ServiceStack - 3.9.71.0.  I found some old docs, and it looks like I'd do this:  

`public override void Configure(Container container) {  
  SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    GlobalHtmlErrorHttpHandler = new RazorHandler("/oops"),
 });
}`  

But, actually, I don't want to use RazorHandler.  So, I assume I could make my own class that extends EndpointHandlerBase, overriding ProcessRequest to do what I want?

Comment: To follow up for anyone looking the in the future, I did the above (see comment) and it worked.  The one trick was also returning a new HttpError within the HandleException override of ServiceRunner